# run c using gcc compiler on lubuntu

Tags: c, unix, ubuntu

i'm about a week behind in my intermediate prg class (due to ram issues) and i just need to ask a very, very simple question.

what commands do i use to run?

i'm using lxterminal on lubuntu. not sure if it's important, but i used gvim to code. i made the file goodhello.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

i compiled using `gcc blah/goodhello.c` without any errors (it didn't report anything).

how do i run it from here?

an `a.out` file appears in the parent directory (which is kind of strange), but when i write `a.out` it says command not found. when i write make a.out it writes nothing to be done. `make goodhello.c` --> `nothing to be done`.

please help!

Comment: i seemed to have figured it out:

Comment: thanks everyone for the quick responses anyways.

Comment: Save yourself much future effort and compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra filename.c`, or put `gcc() { command gcc -Wall -Wextra "$@"; }` and `export CFLAGS='-Wall -Wextra'` in your .bashrc

Comment: @william-pursell could you possibly clarify what those arguments do? It's not clear from gcc help..

Comment: -Wall turns on (almost) all warnings and -Wextra turns on even more.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify which directory the program can be found. This is usually the current directory in the situation you've shown, and would be expressed with `./`. So you should be able to use

```
./a.out
```

As @HunterMcMillen pointed out, the reason for having to use ./ is because, unlike Windows, *nix based systems dont include the current directory in the search path. (In Windows, you can just run an executable by typing its name while in the same directory.)

Comment: It might be worth pointing out the reason for having to use `./` is because the current directory on unix based systems in not included in the PATH, unlike Windows where you can just run an executable by typing its name `foo.exe`.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: Thanks. Added that info (with attibution) to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your shell don't understand where to find a file you try to run, so just enter it:

```
./a.out
```

Where ./ is current directory.